# Why is the method :try called on Array instead of ActiveRecord::Relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an instruction like this:

```
project.memberships.try(:destroy_all)
```

Obviously, a project has many memberships. When that's executed I get `undefined method :destroy_all for class Array`.

So the question is why is the method called on `Array` and not on `ActiveRecord::Relation`? Also when I try `project.memberships.class` it returns `Array` but `project.memberships.where(nil)` returns `ActiveRecord::Relation`. Is it a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: What version of rails? I think this behavior is slightly different depending on the version you're using.

Comment: Your are trying to run non Relation method, so it runs this relation and returns result, so I think it's correct behavior

Comment: Certainly. Now that I think it, `project.memberships` should not be `nil` never but `[]` if empty.